# How to write wrapper function so that compiler efficiently optimize it?

Tags: c, optimization, code-generation

I have a function which do basic error checking before returning next node of the link list:

```
Node *next_node(Node *n) {
  switch(type(n)){
    case A:
    case B:
.
.
    case N:
      return n->next;
    default:
      exit(1); //This is just a representation of my code handling error scenario.
  }
}
```

There are more wrapper functions on top of it which does certain things depending upon return value of above mentioned function.

These wrapper functions are being used extensively in my whole code base. It is too much that when I run profiler, I found them as time consuming routines. 
This do make sense to me because there are thousands of function calls from different code area to these functions and such number of calls will definitely take time due to function call overheading and/or instruction cache misses.

I also know that compilers do some optimization around these, so that they can be inlined while generating assembly code. It seems that it is not working properly because of current way of implementation.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the common way of writing such wrapper functions so that compiler can optimize them for low runtime?
2. How do other companies handle such a scenario in their code base?

Note1: code above is just for representation, there are lot of such wrapper function in the whole code base. Therefore, if someone has any idea on improving upon runtime issue due to wrapper functions, should share the idea.

Note2: I'm using gcc as compiler and my code base is entirely in C.

Comment: Do you run gcc with optimization enabled (`-O3`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you seem to be in a correct case for low level optimization because you have profiled your code and found a time consuming function.

Assuming that you already use the higher optimization level of your compiler, the bad part it that there is no general answer to such a question. I can only give you some hints here:

- are some redundant operations somewhere? if yes you can try to make sure that you do them only once
- are there complex loops that could be unwinded? not much to gain but some tests at the price of a longer code
- is assembly code an option? if yes you can try to write all or part of the function in assembly language

But you could (should?) also wonder whether:

- the general structure of your application is correct - if you can manage to less call the function you spend less time in it...
- you really need the tests in production code. If they are assertions more than tests, they should only be conditionally included with a `#ifdef` in tests and debug versions.